# Fixed size bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make container fixed size `750px` for all sized windows. 
Here is `HTML`:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="thumbnail" >
            ..........<br/>
            ..........
        </div>
</div>
```

and custom `CSS`:

```
   @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        width: 750px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        width: 750px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 750px;
    }
```

But the problem is when I am resizing window from big to small at some point size of `thumbnail` is getting a little larger and then reverses to its initial size.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/718/ . You can just resize browser window or slide inner window in fiddle itself to left and then to right to reproduce this behavior.

I have tried to add another div with `row` class. Tried combinations with `col-sm`, `col-md` etc, but I can not manage to achieve desired behavior. How can I fix this so the container/thumbnail size stays the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to close the @media brackets.

```
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        width: 750px !important;
    }
}
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        width: 750px !important;
    }
}
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
         width: 750px !important;
    }
}


.container{ width: 750px !important;}
.thumbnail{ width: 750px !important;}
```

Comment: You are my hero! That was the exact problem... Can't believe that I have missed that.